# Add device UDID to Free iOS Development Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have created a Free iOS Development Provisioning Profile to test my app. Now I want to share the app to my friend and I have the UDID of the device. As I don't have the device to run the app to run it on xcode. How can I add the device udid to that Provisioning Profile to share the app.

Comment: You can't, since a free account has no access to the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles in the developers portal.

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Developer Portal (developer.apple.com) > Account > Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles.

In the left menu, select Devices and click the + button to add a new device.  Give it a name and enter the UDID here.

Now go to your provisioning profile.  Click on it and select Edit. Where it says Devices, select your new device that you just added.  Generate that provisioning profile and download it to Xcode.

Your new device is now added to your provisioning profile and you can run the app on that device.

Comment: in a free account you cant add udid

Comment: That option is not for a free developer account

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer Portal (developer.apple.com) > Account > Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles > Iphone(Device)

[image]

Comment: That option is not for a free developer account